How to position one iterator over another in sum operator?
I need a formula to look like this:

My LaTeX code
\begin{equation}
    \psi( \vec{v}; \vec{d}_j ) = \tilde{\psi}(v_j) + \sum\limits_{n=1 \\ n\neq j}^N \hat{\psi}(v_n; d_{j, n})
\end{equation}

does not place n=1 over n!=j:

What have I done wrong?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

You don't need \limits; what you want is \sum_{\substack{n=1\\n\neq j}}^{N}.
